# add 2 variables of XTemplate in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to add 2 member variables of Xtemplate.
I tried something like this

```
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
                    record: 'RealTimeFlow'
            },[
                    {name: 'successEvent', mapping: '@sEvents'},
                    {name: 'successLatency', mapping : '@sLatency'},
                    {name: 'failedEvent', mapping: '@fEvents'},
                    {name: 'failedPercent', mapping: '@fPercent'},
                    {name: 'failedLatency', mapping : '@fLatency'}
            ])
      });

 var RTFtpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
 '<p align="left">Total Events:{[values.successEvent+values.failedEvent]}<br \>',.........................
```

If success event = 40 and failed event = 6

then the answer should be 44 ...... but by using the above I am getting 406

Any idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the problem

in the store added the type value to the variables

```
 reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
                record: 'RealTimeFlow'
        },[
                {name: 'successEvent', mapping: '@sEvents', type : 'int'},
                {name: 'successLatency', mapping : '@sLatency'},
                {name: 'failedEvent', mapping: '@fEvents',type : 'int'},
                {name: 'failedPercent', mapping: '@fPercent'},
                {name: 'failedLatency', mapping : '@fLatency'}
        ]),
        newDate : new Date()
  });
```

and

```
var RTFtpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
 '<p align="left">Total Events:{[values.successEvent+values.failedEvent]}<br \>',
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is adding two strings together

'40' + '6' = '406' in Javascript

Try parsing them as numbers. You could use parseInt perhaps, or make sure that the values are numbers in your model.

Comment: Didnt work either ........ Total Events: {[ParseInt(values.successEvent) + ParseInt(values.failedEvenT)]}  throws an error ............ " Object expected ext-js all. "